# Docker commit issue

Tags: docker, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I was following the below tutorial to [create hyperledger fabric](http://fabric-rtd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#create-join-channel).

Post creating the channel whenever I try to perform a docker commit a new image is created. Once the image got created I restarted the container and during restart I get the below error:

> vijaygopal@vijaygopal-VirtualBox:~/hyperledger/fabric/release/samples/e2e$ CHANNEL_NAME=vijaygopalchannel docker-compose -f docker-compose-no-tls.yaml up -d
>   Creating network "e2e_default" with the default driver
>   Creating orderer.example.com
>   Creating peer0.org1.example.com
>
> ERROR: for peer0.org1.example.com  Cannot create container for service peer0.org1.example.com: cannot mount volume over existing file, file exists  /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/8b1dc694a2d0fdef17160d6b6f81d86fd6289192d2cdfa77a5f6f9cc185c5435/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel.tx
>   ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial hosted at that address is a defunct build artifact. Not sure how you found it, but it is not authoritative and significantly dated. Please use the published [Hyperledger Fabric 1.0.x documentation](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)